# Date validation and conversion to European format Python

Tags: python, validation, date, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to write code (Python) that would check date format of an input and then convert it to DD-MM-YYYY (if input format differs from DD-MM-YYYY). I have checked similar questions on StackOverflow but they are all concerned with either validating or converting format and I have no idea how to do both at the same time. I can't block input in other formats as it comes from external source.

So far I wrote this:

```
import datetime
YearOfBirthString = '05-30-1960'
if YearOfBirthString != '':
    if datetime.datetime.strptime(YearOfBirthString, '%d-%m-%Y'):
        print(YearOfBirthString)
    elif datetime.datetime.strptime(YearOfBirthString, '%Y-%m-%d'):
        correctDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(YearOfBirthString, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        print(correctDate)
    elif datetime.datetime.strptime(YearOfBirthString, '%m-%d-%Y'):
        correctDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(YearOfBirthString, '%m-%d-%Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        print(correctDate)
    elif datetime.datetime.strptime(YearOfBirthString, '%Y-%d-%m'):
        correctDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(YearOfBirthString, '%Y-%d-%m').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        print(correctDate)
    else:
        print('Nuffin')
else:
    print('Nuffin')
```

It works only when the first "If" condition is meet- crashes in any other cases instead of checking all elif conditions. Error message is as follow:

> "ValueError: time data '05-30-1960' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'"

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: instead of conditions, `try....except` and catch the conversion errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure your logic in a function to attempt, sequentially, several `datetime` formats in a `for` loop. Then `return` when a specific format succeeds.

This solution involves only `datetime` from the standard library and `try` / `except` to capture unsuccessful attempts.

```
from datetime import datetime

YearOfBirthString = '05-30-1960'

def converter(s, format_list, format_output):
    for date_format in format_list:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(s, date_format).strftime(format_output)
        except ValueError:
            continue      
    return 'Nuffin'

res = converter(YearOfBirthString,
                format_list=['%d-%m-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m-%d-%Y', '%Y-%d-%m'],
                format_output='%d-%m-%Y')

# '30-05-1960'
```

Comment: Big Thank You! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use **[dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)**.

**Demo:**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime
YearOfBirthString = ['05-30-1960', '1960-05-30', '30-05-1960', '1960-30-05']
for date in YearOfBirthString:
    try:
        print( parse(date).strftime('%d-%m-%Y') )
    except:
        cDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%d-%m').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        print( cDate )
```

**Output:**

```
30-05-1960
30-05-1960
30-05-1960
30-05-1960
```